# Facing issue to set up Twitter Access on Watson

Tags: twitter, watson

I am trying to setup Twitter Access on Watson.
I tried following the steps provided in the below link.
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Twitter/index.html#insights_twitter_overview
I am unable to proceed with Step1 - "Navigate to your application overview page". Where can find the application overview page?

Could you please help me out?

Thanks,
Rohit

Answer (score 0):

The Insights for Twitter service in the above link is available in IBM Bluemix: https://console.ng.bluemix.net

If you have a Bluemix account and created an application, you can add the service instance.